# Magnific jquery version update

Tags: magnific-popup

We love the library and use it extensively as we do Syncfusion.  We would love to update to the latest Syncfusion, yet both codebases rely on jquery.  In order to upgrade Syncfusion we must upgrade jquery and Magnific is incompatible with the latest versions.  Are there any plans for an update?

Comment: I certainly can't speak for the Magnific maintainer (and don't see an issue related to this filed in the GitHub repo), but it might help to know what the apparent incompatibility is.

Comment: Very easy to see ones-self.  Pop-ups don't open and there's an error in the console.  The requirements call for version 1.

Comment: No, it's actually not easy for me to see myself. I just tried making a basic Magnific example in jsfiddle, using jQuery 3.4.1. Things worked as expected. No error in my console. So I doubt anybody here can help you unless you actually post what console error you're getting, what browser you're using, what code you're trying (in case it uses different options/features/parameters from what I tried), etc. There are lots of variables that could be impacting the brokenness you're seeing.